# {number}X - Some text on VSCode while typing

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am seeing some text like 27x, 165x, 5x, ... while typing in VSCode. Can anyone help me with what it is arriving for?

[image: This is reference image for same]

Comment: disable all extensions, and enable them one by one to see which is the culprit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the extension "Power Mode", you can disable Or edit your settings.

Example:

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).